# Alterar Palavra ao clicar nela

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho o seguinte campo em meu sistema:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 target" id="cread1nd">
    <div style="width: 150px;" class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="cread1" class="form-control" min="0" max="15" />
        <div style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">mEq/L</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Na segunda `div` que está `mEq/L` precisava de um *script* que quando clicar em `mEq/L` ele alterava somente a letra para `mmol/L`. Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: Totalmente off-topic, mas fiquei interessado pelo seu projeto químico, se precisar de ajuda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode adicionar um evento de [click](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/click) usando como seletor a classe `input-group-addon` para selecionar a `div`, e alterar o texto:

```js
document.querySelector('.input-group-addon').addEventListener('click', function(event){
  if (this.innerHTML == 'mEq/L')
    this.innerHTML = 'mmol/L';
  else
    this.innerHTML = 'mEq/L';
});
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 target" id="cread1nd">
  <div style="width: 150px;" class="input-group ">
    <input type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="cread1" class="form-control" min="0" max="15" />
    <div style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">mEq/L</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: o script é exatamente este, queria saber se tem comom modificar ele pra ficar trocando entre 'mEq/L' para 'mmol/L' é possivel ?

Comment: É possível sim @LeonardoMacedo, mas não foi isso que você pediu, o que de certa forma meio que inválida a minha resposta e a do jbueno.

Comment: Editado @LeonardoMacedo.

Comment: Não consegui me expressar direito, peço desculpas!

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda!, preciso de 5 minutos pra validar como correta a resposta

Answer (score 1):

Basicamente você só precisa definir um evento de click para o elemento. Perceba que eu adicionei um id na div, você pode usar qualquer seletor que quiser, mas cuidado para não adicionar o evento a elementos que não precisam ter este comportamento.

```js
document.getElementById('clique').addEventListener('click', onClick);

function onClick(){
  this.innerText = (this.innerText == 'mmol/L') ? 'mEq/L' : 'mmol/L';
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-2 target" id="cread1nd">
    <div style="width: 150px;" class="input-group ">
        <input type="text" placeholder="00.00" name="cread1" class="form-control" min="0" max="15" />
        <div id="clique" style="background: #E0E1E2;" class="input-group-addon">mEq/L</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: o script é exatamente este, queria saber se tem como modificar ele pra ficar trocando entre 'mEq/L' para 'mmol/L' é possivel ?

Comment: Tá aí a edição. Bom proveito